# How to get HTML SELECT populated from Database

Tags: php, mysqli, html-select

I'm trying to get an HTML SELECT field within a form to be populated from a database column.  I can read the column fine, and can use fprint or echo to see the results.  The problem is, I can't seem to get the array based on the column to appear as selections in the SELECT field.  I'm able to produce a field with a pull-down selector, but the values aren't populated.  How to I get the values from the Array into an HTML SELECT / OPTION field?
Here's a subset of the code I'm using:

```
<?php 
$link = new mysqli("localhost","USER","PASSWORD", "DATABASE");
  if (mysqli_connect_errno())
   {
   printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
  exit();
}
if (!$link->set_charset("utf8")) 
{
    printf("Error loading character set utf8: %s\n", $link->error);
    exit();
}

$role_sql = "SELECT role FROM lu_role";
$role_result = mysqli_query($link, $role_sql);
$options = "";
while($row1 = mysqli_fetch_array($role_result))
{
        $options = $options."<option>$row1[1]</option>";
}

//Using the following to validate that I can get the query results in an array.
while ($row = $role_result->fetch_assoc())
{
    printf($row["role"]);
}
?>
<form action="post.php" method="post">
    <table class="table_600_reg">
      <tr>
        <td width="120">Father</td>
        <td width="200" align="left">
            <select>
                <?php echo $options;?>
            </select>
```

Comment: It should be `$options = $options."<option>$row1[0]</option>";` only one column you are selecting, so index always starts with 0 not with 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing `value=""` here `$options = $options."<option value='VALUE_HERE'>$row1[1]</option>";`

And since you are selecting only one column it should be `$row1[0]` instead of `$row1[1]`

Comment: Without value, option can take a place.

Comment: `value` attribute is needed, it indicates what is sent to the server.

Comment: All options would have a blank value with this code.

Comment: And he is having problem with value as he mentioned.

Comment: Because the index should be 0, not 1. Not only would your code be wrong, but it also would provide blank values on POST/GET after OP realized that.

Comment: That's true. I was talking about first comment. @blake

Comment: Thanks Mahfuzul Alam.  That was the problem.  It's working now.  I appreciate the help.

Comment: I give up on this site.

Comment: @Mahfuzul Alam :Yes in that case you are right, thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score 1):

You may check your index in displaying your field. On your query, you only specified a field to be returned:

`SELECT role FROM lu_role`

So the index should start with '0' not '1'.

```
$options = $options."<option>$row1[0]</option>";
```

You may also use 'mysqli_fetch_assoc' so you can use $row1['role'] instead of relying on the index.

Comment: Note: If you changed your query to `SELECT name,role FROM lu_role` `name` would become index 0, and `role` would be index 1. Its reference is ambiguous. Use associative references so your code is understandable at a glance.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
$options = "";
while($row1 = mysqli_fetch_array($role_result))
{
        $options .= "<option value='".$row1['role']."'>$row1['role']</option>";
}
```

and then can you able to use

```
<select>
      <option value="">Select one</option>
      <?php echo $options;?>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would personally refer to the associative array values instead of the indexed values. If you later decided you wanted to pull more results from that table to manipulate other data, the index could change.

```
while ($row = $role_result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $options .= "<option value='{$row['role']}'>{$row['role']}</option>";
}
```

Answer (score -1):

you need to put your while statement inside the **select tag**

here is the code

```
<select>
<?php
while($row1 = mysqli_fetch_array($role_result))
{
        $options = $options."<option>$row1[1]</option>";
        echo '$options';

}

?>
            </select>
```

Comment: This would definitely duplicate options each loop. And it doesn't **need** to be placed there.

Comment: sorry i was thinking its the same idea as mysqli_fetch_assoc()